# Clicking content below image with higher z-index

Tags: jquery, css, z-index, css-position

I have created a slider using jquery and the [slides plugin](http://slidesjs.com/). I wanted to create an effect where it looks like the slider is circular shaped, so I positioned an image with a transparent circular center absolutely above the slider, with a higher z-index. You can see a working example here:  http://vitaminjdesign.com/example/examples/Standard/index.html

The problem I have having is that you cannot click on anything within the slider, because of the "mask image" which has a higher z-index than the rest of the content. I want to be able to click on the links within the caption area, as well as the entire slide. Does anybody have any good ideas on how to solve this issue?

I cannot give .caption a higher z-index than the mask because then you would see the background pass above the circular mask. BUT I need to be able to click within the transparent area of the image mask. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@JCHASE11 I didnt think i would ever suggest this to anyone.. I just had to do it when i saw your solution.. its just.. suffocating.. but.. how about image mapping? - http://jsfiddle.net/u9cYZ/

Hah.. I started having second thoughts about this.. but it is indeed doable with image map.

Ended up testing it to make sure that im not just throwing around ideas that wont work.. http://jsfiddle.net/u9cYZ/3/ ( In this example IE gets value img position: relative; from somewhere which screws it up and..It's too late I'm off to bed )

So the solution is still a little.. crafty.. but this time it would only cover the wanted area..

---

This is a bit of a duct tape idea.. But, I was thinking that you could put an empty `<a>` in there somewhere, on top of the mask of course and change the `href` to match the current visible image.

Comment: this works very well and is the first time I've messed with image maps. Are they an OK practice??

Comment: @JCHASE11 Perfectly fine, though unless I remember wrong they wont validate with strict doctype. But that shouldnt be An issue. They are most often used for maps and maps only these days but anything goes really. Also http://www.w3.org/TR/html40/struct/objects.html#h-13.6

Comment: @JCHASE11 Oh and just incase.. if you're using Chrome.. it doesnt show the area in the dev tools as the circle that it is, Firebug does. ( Easier to edit the area when you can actually see it. )

Answer (score 2):

It seems, that your slider returns false, when a click on a link occurs. So give much attention to the next line in the code `window.location.href = myLink.attr('href');`

```
$('#slides #mask').click(function (e) {

    // user click coordinates
    var cursorPosX = e.pageX;
    var cursorPosY = e.pageY;

    $('#slides .caption a').each(function () {
        var myLink = $(this);

        // coordinates of the link at the moment
        var linkPosLeft = myLink.offset().left;
        var linkPosTop = myLink.offset().top;

        // parameters of the link
        var linkWidth = myLink.width() + linkPosLeft;
        var linkHeight = myLink.height() + linkPosTop;

        // compare...
        if ( cursorPosX >= linkPosLeft && cursorPosX <= linkWidth ) {
            if ( cursorPosY >= linkPosTop && cursorPosY <= linkHeight ) {
                window.location.href = myLink.attr('href');
            }
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: that is exactly the direction I am looking for. I tried using this code and it does not seem to be working in its current order. I uploaded this to the link above so you can see. It looks like nothing happens when the mask is clicked.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using one div for the masked image, I split it up into 6 Divs each having their own background position.
 (see image)[image]

Please see http://vitaminjdesign.com/example/examples/Standard/index.html for updated example.

Comment: Not bad idea, but it will work only if "add a link" is at the very top of its possible position.

Comment: yep! it wont ever be in a lower position because the title will be truncated