# Image to be displayed as a circled Image using css

Tags: html, css

Here's my code - This works in chrome, firefox and safari .. I have tested it on Windows 7
However in IE 8 and Opera browser the following code is not working and instead of showing a circled image I am getting Image in square form

```
<div id="hotspot-img1-0">
  <ul>
    <img class="proimg" src="http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/hprofile-ak-snc4/276311_100002617687873_1118195351_n.jpg" title="web" style="width:100px;height:100px;background:#fff;border:2px solid #ccc;-moz-border-radius:52px;-webkit-border-radius:52px;">
  </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#hotspot-img1-0{
    top: 570px; 
    left: 67px; 
    height: 104px; 
    width: 104px; 
    border-top-left-radius: 52px; 
    border-top-right-radius: 52px; 
    border-bottom-right-radius: 52px; 
    border-bottom-left-radius: 52px; 
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px 0px; 
    border-top-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); 
    border-left-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); 
    border-right-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); 
    border-bottom-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); 
    border-top-width: 2px; 
    border-left-width: 2px; 
    border-right-width: 2px; 
    border-bottom-width: 2px; 
    border-top-style: solid; 
    border-left-style: solid; 
    border-right-style: solid; 
    border-bottom-style: solid
}
```

Comment: for IE it could be because it's not supporting such css properties, try if any hack available (IE) for border radius.

Comment: try and hack it  http://www.htmlremix.com/css/curved-corner-border-radius-cross-browser

Comment: or just make a circle png with transparency it will still be  a square it will just look like a circle

Answer (score 9, accepted):

@Sandhurst; first thing bad markup write like this:

```
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>
       <img class="proimg" src="http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/hprofile-ak-snc4/276311_100002617687873_1118195351_n.jpg" title="web">
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

& Answer for the question use `background-image` instead of `img`  :

```
li{
 background:url(image.jpg) no-repeat;
 -moz-border-radius:52px;
 -webkit-border-radius:52px;
 border-radius:52px;
width:200px;
height:200px;
}
```

Comment: This works but the image is not fitted inside the circle, instead only a portion of it is displayed inside the circle

Comment: for fit the image inside the div write -moz-background-size:100% 100%; -webkit-background-size:100% 100%;

Answer (score 2):

The [`border-radius` CSS3 declaration is unsupported](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html#t46) in Internet Explorer 8 and below. You can use the `-o-border-radius` declaration to get rounded borders in Opera.

[CSS3 Pie](http://css3pie.com/) may help with getting rounded borders in older versions of Internet Explorer, but I'd recommend just leaving them as square images (following the principles of [graceful degradation and progressive enhancement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement)).

Answer (score 1):

It's a CSS3 issue. IE and Opera don't handle it well. You can use a solution like http://fetchak.com/ie-css3/ to resolve it if you would like.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

At present Opera (version 10.5 onward), Safari (version 5 onward) and Chrome (version 5 onward) all support the individual border-*-radius properties and the border-radius shorthand property as natively defined in the current W3C Specification (although there are still outstanding bugs on issues such as border style transitions, using percentages for lengths, etc.).
Mozilla Firefox (version 1.0 onward) supports border-radius with the -moz- prefix, although there are some discrepancies between the Mozilla implementation and the current W3C specification (see below).
Update:Recent Firefox nightly versions support border-radius without the -moz- prefix.
Safari and Chrome (and other webkit based browsers) have supported border-radius with the -webkit- prefix since version 3 (no longer needed from version 5 onward), although again with some discrepancies from the current specification (see this article for further details of how older versions of Webkit handle border-radius).
Even Microsoft have promised, and demonstrated in their recent preview release, support for border-radius from Internet Explorer 9 onward (without prefix).

http://www.css3.info/preview/rounded-border/

Answer (score 0):

Here is a website http://www.danielmall.com/ where the images are being displayed in circle. The author of the website has used jquery and css to get it working with both IE and firefox. Check out the page source and you will get some interesting info on how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Image maps could do it for you.

[Clicking content below image with higher z-index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7102818/clicking-content-below-image-with-higher-z-index/7103253#7103253)

http://jsfiddle.net/u9cYZ/

http://jsfiddle.net/u9cYZ/3/

Answer (score -1):

To my knowledge, there is no way to get Opera or IE to clip an `<img>` to a circle using CSS. border-radius will clip background images set in element styles though.

You might be able to [clip things using SVG](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Applying_SVG_effects_to_HTML_content), but I wasn't able to get any of the examples on that page to work in Opera.

Comment: Also, if you use border-radius on the image, Opera 12 alpha clips the image to a circle, so this will work with the next release of Opera. Just use the unprefixed border-radius on the image too.